# ElasticSearch grouping facets

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have document with such structure:

```
{
    id: 312256,
    name: "SomeName",
    filterBlocks: [{
            id: 0
            filterTypeId: 4
            filterItems: [
                1190
            ]
        }, {
            id: 0
            filterTypeId: 3
            filterItems: [
                353
            ]
        }, {
            id: 234
            filterTypeId: 1
            filterItems: [
                6342
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For each distinct combination of filterBlocks.id+filterBlocks.filterTypeId I need N size facets on filterItems field. I try to use query like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "facets": {
        "filterBlocks": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "filterBlocks.filterItems"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But of course I get only N facets without grouping  by filterBlocks.id+filterBlocks.filterTypeId

What' I need modify in my query or document structure to get it right? Thank's

Comment: So you either want a dynamic number of facet (one facet per `filterBlocks.id`/`filterBlocks.filterType` combination) or some sort of grouping like `GROUP BY filterTypeId`. As far as i know neither is possible with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first query to get all filterBlocks.id/filterBlocks.filterType combinations, then iterate through the results to build a facet search with a facet filter for each combination.

Using a terms facet on the first query will probably be a good way to get a unique set of results.